# Library to print tabular data on a web page

Tags: php, html, css

Are there any libraries I can use to pretty print tabular data(from php code)?

What I mean is, if I have:

```
$headers = array("name", "surname", "email");
$data[0] = array("bill", "gates", "bill@microsoft.com");
$data[1] = array("steve", "jobs", "steve@apple.com");
/*...*/
pretty_print($headers, $data);
```

It will print my data neatly(preferably using tableless html code & css)?

Comment: I don't know of any off hand, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write one yourself. Also, why tableless? Tables are for tabular data!

Comment: @Tyler +1 for correct use of tables.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS: The goal of "tableless" HTML code is only intended for areas that are not tabular in nature, but used to use `<table>` elements to layout a page - rather than using CSS methods.  *Actual tabular data* should still very much be kept in tables where visually sensible.

Comment: @ToAll Thanks for the comments, I'm not against a table based solution, I just don't prefer it in case I have the option. And my question is still valid. It is not `so easy` to code this since one has to take pagination, highlights, border colors, round corner effects etc. into account. And what I am asking is such a common thing that I am sure someone else has done it before. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS: highlights, borders, etc. seem like more of a CSS issue than HTML generation. I'm not even sure what you mean by pagination in this case - why wouldn't you be printing the whole table? If you did only want a subset, then add optional parameters for $offset and $limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write your own?

I wrote an example below. Note that I haven't tested this - it's the definition of "air code" so beware. Also, you could add checks to make sure `count($rows) > 0` or to make sure `count($rows) == count($headers)` or whatever..

The point is just that it isn't *that* hard to throw something together:

```
function displayTable($headings, $rows) {
  if !(is_array($headings) && is_array($data)) {
    return false; //or throw new exception.. whatever  
  }

  echo "<table>\n";
  echo "<thead>\n";
  echo "<tr>\n";
  foreach($headings as $heading) {
    echo "<th>" . $heading . "</th>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
  echo "</thead>\n";

  echo "<tbody>"  
  foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($row as $data) {
      echo "<td>" . $data . "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</tbody>\n";
  echo "</table>\n";
}
```

As a final note, why would you want to use HTML/CSS layouts rather than tables for this? Tables are for *tabular data* which this obviously is. This is their purpose!

The trend against using tables is for using them to layout pages. They're still quite valid for tabular data, and will be for the foreseeable future.